# Applet vulnerabilities

Tags: java, security, applet

Our client has some old site based on applet.
I am trying to show all risk of vulnerabilities.

There is a chank of applet:

```
<applet name="Charts" width="800" height="600" codebase="http://localhost/Charts/DigiClasses/" code="com.MainApplet" archive="Charts.jar" mayscript="">Charts requires a Java Compatible web browser to run.</applet>
```

I use IE11.
Is it possible inject local modified classes on web page instead of server's classes?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't this a moot question? Applets are extinct.

Comment: *"I am trying to show all risk of vulnerabilities"* If Sun/Oracle could have achieved that, they might also have patched the problems and not have seen browser manufacturers remove support for the plug-in that loads applets. Seriously, factor it out now. Move on.